# my android emulator is crashing when running applications

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have installed Android SDK(Build: v21.0.0-531062) in `Windows7`.

My AVD configuration is this device:

- 4.7 WXGA(1280 x720:xhdpi)
- Internal storage 200MB
- SD card 200 MB.

When I am running my application it always crashes and shows a not responding title. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: anything showing in the `logcat`??

Comment: The emulator crashes or just the application?

Comment: Log cat shows many error but I am not able to paste it here because it is very long. My application dont crash. only emulator crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the avd  Ram Size to 512 MB .

Comment: Finally I have found a best solution! I have downloaded SDK for Ubuntu and now the emulator  is atleast 10 times faster than Windows. Also there is no freezing, error etc. It is working fantastically!!!! Thanks to Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have run into a bug of the emulator. Try to create a new AVD, maybe with slightly different parameter and keep fingers crossed ;-)

Comment: I have tried making different AVD but still the problem persists. Do you know where the disk space is allocated for AVD? My WIndows drive automatically get filled up when making new AVDs

Comment: The disk space should be freed when you delete AVDs you do no longer need.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the *CPU* being used: **ARM** / Intel Atom

Try changing the *RAM* size: **512Mb**

Try changing *VM Heap*: **32**

Try lowering *internal storage* size and *SD Card* size: **100Mb**

Try changing the "Emulation Options": *Use Host GPU* (or **not**)

Comment: Still its not working. It will work only if the system shutdown and start after 4-5 hours.